# Asynchronous processing of multiple files in array - Python

Tags: python, arrays, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have an array that gets populated with files every 5 seconds, like:

```
my_files = [file1, file2.., filen]
```

Each one of these files has to go through functions for some kind of processing. For example:

```
def func1:
    do something 
    return result1

def func2(result1):
    do something else
```

And so on. The files are not corelated, however, the outputs of the functions are (e.g. the result of one function is needed for the second etc.)

At the moment my script processes each of the files each one at the time, and therefore it can be quite slow. Is there a way to have my script processing the files as they arrive? I am quite new at programming and I can't quite grasp my head around the asynchronous/parallel programming. I have already looked into asyncio.

Comment: can you put all the functions inside one functions?

Comment: How does your array get populated exactly? Also, what is the most expensive operation, is it the reading of the file or the processing of its content? In any case you might want to look into [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it depends how your processing works. in Python real multiprocessing is done with Multiprocessing library. Threading is on the other hand done with threading library. Threading library is more like asynchronous processing. It will not faster your code, but it will be fast if your code is slowed done by waiting.

this is something you can do:

```
import threading
def all_in_one_function(some_file):
  result = process_file(some_file)
  if result == 'result1':
     do this
  if result == 'result2':
     do that


while True:
    if len(my_files) >0:
        file_to_be_processed = my_files.pop()
        threading.Thread(target = all_in_one_function,args=(file_to_be_processed,)).start()
# you pop the files from your array and process it asyncronously, everytime a file appears it will be popped out of array and processed
```

As far as threadding is concerned I advice you to thread one function. That means, have a function that will simply do all the processing. Or create class that will do the processing(passes args between functions) and thread the initialized object.

I prefer creating one function with all processing.
You dont want to go deep in passing arguments between threads...